# vaadin - Is it possible to change the path in dynamic resources?

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin14

I use the StreamResource to generate an url for dynamically download resource like PDF files that I build dynamiccaly in my application.

The url generated is like :
`VAADIN/dynamic/resource/0/a82e9736-8d39-4960-873a-eaf57943b71f/pdf-file.pdf`

Is it possible to change this path (remove words VAADIN/dynamic for example) ? and if yes, how ?
I use vaadin 14

Thank you

Comment: Not as far as I know

Comment: Only if you use your won servlet to deliver content, but then it's outside of the vaadin scope